# Intuition for a proof that the rationals are incomplete.

Tags: intuition, rational-numbers

> Let A be a set of positive rationals $p$ such that $p^2<2$. Now this set contains no upper bound. To prove this, for every rational $p$, a number $p- \frac{p^2-2}{p+2}$ is associated. This number (let's call it $q$) is greater than $p$. Also, it can be proved that $q^2<2$. Now the proof is complete.

I don't know if this is the only proof of this theorem but anyway how could one come up with that number to be associated with $p$. I am interested in the thought process behind.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14970/no-maximumminimum-of-rationals-whose-square-is-lessergreater-than-2

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448575/intuition-behind-proof-in-the-rudin-book-that-there-is-no-largest-smallest-real and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141774/choice-of-q-in-baby-rudins-example-1-1

Comment: What's your question.

Comment: @Bungo's first link is really quite a good find for this exact question.

Answer (score 0):

First prove $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q} $
then let $T:=\{p \in \mathbb{Q} : p^2<2\}$

Then prove that $\sup T = \sqrt{2} $
.Finally $\sup T \notin \mathbb{Q}$

$\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete.

Comment: I think their main question is about the number being called $q$.